# Fast method for combining two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I have two lists, `v1` and `v2`. Each element of the lists may be positive or negative. I want to create a list `v3` whose entry `i` is `v1[[i]]` if `v1[[i]]` is posive, but otherwise is `v2[[i]]`.

The trivial way to implement this is to use a `For`-loop with `If`. Is there any faster way?

I tried using logical operator:

```
vP = Boole[Positive[v1]]; 
vN = Boole[Negative[v2]];
v3 = vP v1 + vN v2;
```

I tought that using logical operations would be faster than going through indices, but instead it is slower. What would be a fast way to do this?

Comment: I think you mean `vN=Boole[Negative[v1]];`

Comment: Also, please note that `Positive@0 == Negative@0 == False`

Comment: vP v1+ (1-vP) v2 ?

Comment: @belisarius. Yes, I mean that. Thanks.

Comment: You got good answers, but I feel that a bit more explanation is in order.  You are on the right track with the approach you tried.  Doing calculations on complete arrays instead of looping through array elements is usually very fast, and it's called "vectorization".  The reason why it wasn't fast in this case is that you were working with symbols rather than numbers: `True` and `False`.  To get optimal performance from Mathematica you need to use homogeneous numerical arrays, which can be [packed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/12).  Arrays with symbols in them ...

Comment: ... cannot be packed.  If you need boolean operations and you're aiming for the best performance using vectorization, it's a good approach to use 1 and 0 instead of True and False.  You can use * and + for the "or" and "and" operations, Unitize is helpful and UnitStep can be used in place of `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
v1 = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 100];
v2 = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 100];
vL = UnitStep[v1];
vL*v1 + (1 - vL)*v2
```

Using PatoCriollo's comparison (and now updated to include rasher and Mr. Wizard's methods):

```
n = 10^6;
v1 = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n];
v2 = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n];

(bp = Boole[Positive[v1]];
test1 = bp v1 + (1 - bp) v2); // Timing

test2 = With[{c = Clip[v1, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]}, c (v1 - v2) + v2]; // Timing

test3 = Table[If[Positive[v1[[i]]], v1[[i]], v2[[i]]], {i, Length@v1}]; // Timing

(vL = UnitStep[v1];
test4 = vL*v1 + (1 - vL)*v2;) // Timing

(vL = UnitStep[v1];
test5 = vL (v1 - v2) + v2;) // Timing

(vL = UnitStep[v1];
test6 = vL Subtract[v1, v2] + v2;) // Timing

(pos = SparseArray[UnitStep[-v1]]["AdjacencyLists"];
  test7 = v1;
  test7[[pos]] = v2[[pos]];) // Timing

{0.479009, Null}
{0.185765, Null}
{0.192930, Null}
{0.100705, Null}
{0.102183, Null}
{0.078348, Null}
{0.087175, Null}

test1 == test2 == test3 == test4 == test5 == test6 == test7
True
```

To summarize: the `UnitStep` method seems the fastest, the `Clip` and `Table` methods are about the same, while `Boole` takes up the rear. All the methods give the same answer. Interestingly, when we change `RandomChoice` to `RandomReal`, the `Clip` and the `UnitStep` methods are about the same speed (and both are faster than `Table` and `Boole`). Using Simon's trick of substituting `Subtract[v1,v2]` for v1-v2 also speeds up the `UnitStep` calculations by a modest, but measurable amount. Mr. Wizard's sparse array approach seems to be competitive with, but slightly slower than the `UnitStep`.

Comment: This is what OP's v3 does, right (with belisarius' typo fix)

Comment: Nope. Gives incorrect result.

Comment: @rasher -- All four methods give the same answer.

Comment: No, they don't. Yours is incorrectly giving `v2` entries where `v1` is zero. Zero is not positive...

Comment: @rasher -- The OP says in the first line: each element may be positive or negative. So the zero case is excluded.

Comment: @bill: Ah, if that's the case, mea culpa

Comment: @rasher -- no worries. Looks like the `Clip` and `UnitStep` are the same speed when doing it with reals. I've added this as well...

Comment: @bills: Except clip will get the right answer always with reals ;-). OP should clarify if *only* non-zero elements, because if so, you're clever solution should be unbeatable.

Comment: You can get a bit more speed by rearranging the expression to remove one of the multiplications: `vL (v1 - v2) + v2`, and then a bit more by using `Subtract`: `vL Subtract[v1, v2] + v2`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method using `SparseArray` properties to find positions (indexes), then `Part` to make the replacements.  It may be a bit more general than the mathematical methods and it appears to be roughly as efficient on my system (running version 7).  Note that unless it is acceptable to count zero as positive it is inappropriate to use `UnitStep[v1]` -- instead use `UnitStep[-v1]` to watershed in the other direction.

Sample data:

```
SeedRandom[7]
MatrixForm[ {v1, v2} = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {2, 15}] ]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
 -1 & 2 & -1 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 4 \\
 5 & 4 & -2 & 5 & 1 & -3 & 2 & 5 & 1 & -3 & -4 & -2 & -4 & -2 & -4
\end{array}
\right)$

```
pos = SparseArray[UnitStep[-v1]]["AdjacencyLists"];
v3 = v1;
v3[[pos]] = v2[[pos]];
v3
```

> ```
> {5, 2, -2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 5, 1, -3, -4, -2, -4, -2, 4}
> ```

Comment: Clean. I like it, +1

Comment: @rasher Thank you.  I wish `Position` were as fast; then it would be even cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

```
With[{c = Clip[v1, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]}, c (v1 - v2) + v2]
```